# Iterate through an array in angularjs

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, iteration

i want to iterate through array elements and print them one by one.
currently i have this HTML code.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in range">
    <div ng-repeat="rhit in hits[i]">
      <p > {{ rhit }}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

here

- "range" is an array with values till 100([0,1,2,....,100])
- "hits" is an array containing more than one element

if i try separately printing like this, it works

```
<p > {{ hit[0] }}</p>
<p > {{ hit[1] }}</p>
<p > {{ hit[2] }}</p>
```

i also tried this code but it doesn't print anything.

```
<div ng-repeat="rhit in hits">
     <p > {{ rhit }}</p>
</div>
```

this is my actual query result

> "aggregations": { "by_id": { "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
>   "sum_other_doc_count": 0, "buckets": [ {
>
> {"key":"60","doc_count":21,
>
> "tops":{
>
> "hits":{
>
> "total":21,"max_score":2.2237754,
>
> "hits":[{"_index":"automatch_testing","_type":"temp_135","_id":"AVU7i0nnXK6g_oqHu-az","_score":2.2237754,"_source":{"t_pacs_id":"34","t_id":"60","matching":"MO"}},
>
> {"_index":"automatch_testing","_type":"temp_143","_id":"AVU7iOSeXK6g_oqHu-XY","_score":2.2237754,"_source":{"t_pacs_id":"30","t_id":"60","matching":"MO","t_match":"matched"}},
>
> {"_index":"automatch_testing","_type":"temp_135","_id":"AVU7i0nlXK6g_oqHu-ay","_score":2.2237754,"_source":{"t_pacs_id":"28","t_id":"60","matching":"MO","UICriteria":"135","t_match":"matched"}}]}}}

here i want to print the field "t_pacs_id" of each document in hits...

is there any way the above code can be run?? please suggest.

many thanks.

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpPrHinSuHM7Pv8miA18?p=info)

Comment: can you please supply more information about your data than "•"hits" is an array containing more than one element"?  right now, it's not clear if it is a typo between `hit` and `hits` or if it is a problem with your data layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested to get the `hits` collection `i`th place then you could directly do `hits[i]` instead of having another `ng-repeat`

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in range">
    <p> {{ hits[i] }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your update in question in big change in what you were asking before.. it would be great if you could provide us an plunkr/fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

You say that separately printing something like this works:

```
<p > {{ hit[0] }}</p>
```

In that code, you are accessing an array named "hit", but in your code that does not work, you are using ng-repeat to iterate over an array named "hits". What do you get when you try:

```
<div ng-repeat="rhit in hit[i]">
```

Comment: What is the output of: <p > {{ hit[0] }}</p>    ? (And can you verify that the value of hit[0] is an array?)